# Can I extract the database from an app on my phone?

Tags: android, database, apk

(How) Is it possible to extract the sql-file from an android application on my pc? We developed an app and used it on some devices but unfortunately some of them didn't save the information on our web interface. So we need the database from three phones and typing by hand is out of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, depending on where it is saved you can access the .db file via the device file explorer on the right in Android Studio.

I assume it is in `data/data/yourPackageName/databases`

There should be .db files, but again, they could be somewhere else depending on the way you created it.

Comment: Do I need root access / debug mode?

Comment: No the app only has to be in debug mode afaik